# Spring MVC: delete/remove a model attribute at jsp

Tags: spring-mvc

In our springMVC web application, we set a model attribute at one of the controller servlet as given below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "page.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goToPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
.....
model.addAttribute("proceed", "true");
.....
}
```

We access this attribute in our jsp file as given below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="proceed" name="proceed" value="${proceed}"/>
```

What we want is: after accessing the attribute, we want to delete/remove this model attribute at jsp file.

Please provide scriptlets that can delete/remove the model attribute. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can bind form values into a model using name attribute of form elements (inputs, textarea). If you wish not to let it displayed again once, then just remove

```
value="${proceed}"
```

from that input tag in your HTML. I hope this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jstl:

```
<c:remove var="proceed" scope="request"/>
```

I am not sure about the scope:
try one of them :`page, request, session ou application`